# iPod accessory protocol USB and Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, usb, external-accessory, mfi

Can we connect two iOS devices simultaneously with an accessory using the iPod accessory protocol - one over USB and other over Bluetooth?

I read the documentation for MFi documentation, but couldn't find any info regarding multiple device connections.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking through the latest documentation again, searching for 'multiple'.  Sorry to be vague, but 'the rules'....

Depends on the Bluetooth connection type.  Connecting via CoreBluetooth shouldn't be an issue.